# A place of space-time where the only fundamental interaction will be the gravitational forces: does make sense?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, interactions, weak-interaction, strong-force

We know that there are four (fundamental forces) fundamental interactions of nature, [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction).

I'm curious about if we can speculate that there exists a place of the space-time in which, after some events have occurred (and we ask about what can be these conditions), for each mass in such a location we can assume that (our mass) it is only subjected/constrained to gravitational interaction, that is thus the other three forces are disconnected. That is, a place of the Universe in which I can presume that the only *connected* interaction on my mass is the gravity: the other forces *are disconnected* (on my mass).

I am looking a place/region of our Universe, and thus that was created by nature* after some event have occurred in such place.

Is such speculation feasible in the nature of our Universe? What event should occur in a space-time location that would make it possible for each mass located at that point experimenting the gravitational forces, but the other three forces to be disconnected (there isn't electromagnetism, nor weak/strong forces)?

---

*I don't say in a laboratory (if such an experiment that I evoke can be performed in a laboratory).

Comment: I hope that my questions have physical meaning. Thanks!

Comment: Your body is held together with the electromagnetical interaction between your atoms. The nuclei of the atoms of your body are held together by the strong interaction. The deuteron nuclei of the (not too much) heavy water in your body would become unstable without the weak interaction, and the resulting radiation would kill you on the spot.

Comment: What do you understand on "connected" and "disconnected" interactions?

Comment: Well, many thanks for your feedback @peterh  I mean that the only interaction that have effects should be the gravitational interaction, the other forces should not have effects on my region on the mass.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about potential dark matter candidates that *only* interact gravitationally (as opposed to something like a WIMP which interacts weakly as well)?

Comment: @user174701 If they don't have effect, you die on the spot.

Comment: @enumaris many thanks. Not, I am asking about a candidate of a place of space-time and events/conditons for which each mass of ordinary matter experiments only the effects of the gravitational field, but doesn't experiment any of the other fundamental forces. I as asking this as speculation, can there be such a place and conditions?

Comment: Matter feels a force because of its own properties, e.g. quarks feel the strong force because they have "color charge". So either you need matter that has no standard-model charges (right-handed neutrinos?), or you need some kind of space-filling particle condensate that acts as an insulator for all the non-gravitational forces (if such a thing is even possible).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here by "connected" & "disconnected". Anything made from normal matter consists of atoms that are bound together electromagnetically, and the nucleons in those atoms are bound by the (residual) strong interaction. Don't they count as connected? Also consider that open space is filled with the electromagnetic radiation of the CMB. If you want a region of space without CMB radiation you need to completely surround the region by an appropriate electromagnetic shield.

Comment: I read and appreciate all the comments above. I am an amateur and I can not add more details to my questions. Thank you very much for everyone's attention to you @MitchellPorter and PM_2Ring . Yes, maybe your idea about that I'm interested in an insulator for all the non-gravitational forces (a region of the nature in which all the non-gravitational forces have not effects) is closer to my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing would correspond to a region of space that contains no matter at all, and no electromagnetic radiation.  However, it could contain gravitational fields and gravitational radiation.

There is an object that theoretically *could* exist, called a "[gravitational geon](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9610074.pdf)", which consists of gravitational waves so intense that the gravitation of their effective mass is sufficient to confine them.  Some physicists have thought that maybe elementary particles are geons.  However, the existence of geons is purely speculative

It could be argued that the region around an uncharged, non-magnetic black hole with no surrounding matter would fit the specifications of your gravitation-only region of space.

The big challenge would be to find a place in the universe that contains exactly zero photons, neutrinos, etc.  There probably is no such place-- only places where the density of such things is greatly reduced.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer (the article seems very good, I'm an amateur). I am going to need some days to choice an answer but yours is vey good.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard Model interactions are based on the fact that the universe has specific gauge symmetries, U(1) for electromagnetic, SU(2) for weak, and SU(3) for strong. The reason why the universe has these specific symmetries is not well understood (at least not by everyone), but it is believed that hey are universal and exist everywhere.

If you want to take ordinary matter and put it in a region where the Standard Model interactions do not exist, then there should be no gauge symmetries in this region. Two problems here. One is that no such regions have been observed. The other is that the border conditions of such a region would be rather special. For example, with no electromagnetic interactions, this region would not be transparent for light.

There is no known process that would remove the universal symmetries of nature at a particular location in space. Even a black hole retains the electric charge, if a charged object falls in.

If instead of ordinary matter you use dark matter, then it would interact only gravitationally in any region of space. However dark matter has not been observed, plus it is currently unknown if dark matter also imteracts weakly.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am going to need some days to choice an answer but yours is vey good.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very difficult for me to choose between both answers.

Comment: @user174701 This is perfectly fine, you select the answer most helpful with your question. Plus S. McGrew is smart and helped me with questions as well. However, this is a clear indication that you have not properly phrased your question, because essentially he and I are answering two different questions. His answer is for the space where electromagnetic interactions conceptually exist, but just are not there at the moment. So just a normal space with no charge particles present. My answer is for the space where the electromagnetic interactions are not possible. Which was your question about?

Comment: I think that the second one, yours. The problem is that I am asking this as amateur and don't understand very well the answers. The nuance between both answers is very thin.

Comment: It is not thin. This is a rough analogy, but you can compare light and sound by asking, in what type of space only light can go, but sound cannot. Then my answer is, in a vacuum, but the other answer would be, just be quiet and make no sound. Clearly the difference is not thin at all between a loudspeaker running at  a full power yet making no sound whatsoever in a vacuum and a loudspeaker sitting in your living room, but disconnected from the signal.

Comment: The objective here is to learn. If you've learned anything from either answer, then the objective is accomplished.

Comment: I am going to try improve my questions in the future here in this site, many thanks for your words.